# CMP and 2's complement

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I've started learning about the `CMP` instruction, which compares two integers.
When using unsigned integers, I read that:

- `ZF=1` means destination and source are equal.
- `ZF=0 && CF = 0` means `destination > source`
- `ZF=0 && CF = 1` means `destination < source`

As I understand, the CMP instruction uses an implied subtraction without changing the value of the operands.
The subtraction **doesn't make sense!**

Let's say I execute the following instruction:

```
 CMP 1, 4
     1 - 4 = 1 + (-4)
    ...001
    .+.100
     =  101
```

I see no carry around here, I mean, the carry out bit is `0`, isn't it? So what I said above, that I read is correct, is wrong.
I just don't understand why this subtraction sets the carry flag. **I did not carry a single bit!** If the carry bit is simply the (in this case) 4th bit of the number, it is zero.
I've spent hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Where's your sign in those binary numbers? -4 is 0FFFFFFFCh in two's complement (32 bits).

Comment: "carry" can be synonymous with "borrow", depending on what the last executed instruction was...

Comment: This is processor dependent. Assuming this is X86, then compare or subtract use the carry bit as a borrow bit. The overflow bit is set based on the assumption that the numbers are signed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so lets try all the 3 bit numbers in a 3 bit system

```
000 - 000 = 0000 :  +0  -  +0  =  + 0      Z
000 - 001 = 1111 :  +0  -  +1  =  +15 [-1] C
000 - 010 = 1110 :  +0  -  +2  =  +14 [-2] C
000 - 011 = 1101 :  +0  -  +3  =  +13 [-3] C
000 - 100 = 1100 :  +0  -  +4  =  +12 [-4] C
000 - 101 = 1011 :  +0  -  +5  =  +11 [-5] C
000 - 110 = 1010 :  +0  -  +6  =  +10 [-6] C
000 - 111 = 1001 :  +0  -  +7  =  + 9 [-7] C
001 - 000 = 0001 :  +1  -  +0  =  + 1      
001 - 001 = 0000 :  +1  -  +1  =  + 0      Z
001 - 010 = 1111 :  +1  -  +2  =  +15 [-1] C
001 - 011 = 1110 :  +1  -  +3  =  +14 [-2] C
001 - 100 = 1101 :  +1  -  +4  =  +13 [-3] C
001 - 101 = 1100 :  +1  -  +5  =  +12 [-4] C
001 - 110 = 1011 :  +1  -  +6  =  +11 [-5] C
001 - 111 = 1010 :  +1  -  +7  =  +10 [-6] C
010 - 000 = 0010 :  +2  -  +0  =  + 2      
010 - 001 = 0001 :  +2  -  +1  =  + 1      
010 - 010 = 0000 :  +2  -  +2  =  + 0      Z
010 - 011 = 1111 :  +2  -  +3  =  +15 [-1] C
010 - 100 = 1110 :  +2  -  +4  =  +14 [-2] C
010 - 101 = 1101 :  +2  -  +5  =  +13 [-3] C
010 - 110 = 1100 :  +2  -  +6  =  +12 [-4] C
010 - 111 = 1011 :  +2  -  +7  =  +11 [-5] C
011 - 000 = 0011 :  +3  -  +0  =  + 3      
011 - 001 = 0010 :  +3  -  +1  =  + 2      
011 - 010 = 0001 :  +3  -  +2  =  + 1      
011 - 011 = 0000 :  +3  -  +3  =  + 0      Z
011 - 100 = 1111 :  +3  -  +4  =  +15 [-1] C
011 - 101 = 1110 :  +3  -  +5  =  +14 [-2] C
011 - 110 = 1101 :  +3  -  +6  =  +13 [-3] C
011 - 111 = 1100 :  +3  -  +7  =  +12 [-4] C
100 - 000 = 0100 :  +4  -  +0  =  + 4 [-4] 
100 - 001 = 0011 :  +4  -  +1  =  + 3      
100 - 010 = 0010 :  +4  -  +2  =  + 2      
100 - 011 = 0001 :  +4  -  +3  =  + 1      
100 - 100 = 0000 :  +4  -  +4  =  + 0      Z
100 - 101 = 1111 :  +4  -  +5  =  +15 [-1] C
100 - 110 = 1110 :  +4  -  +6  =  +14 [-2] C
100 - 111 = 1101 :  +4  -  +7  =  +13 [-3] C
101 - 000 = 0101 :  +5  -  +0  =  + 5 [-3] 
101 - 001 = 0100 :  +5  -  +1  =  + 4 [-4] 
101 - 010 = 0011 :  +5  -  +2  =  + 3      
101 - 011 = 0010 :  +5  -  +3  =  + 2      
101 - 100 = 0001 :  +5  -  +4  =  + 1      
101 - 101 = 0000 :  +5  -  +5  =  + 0      Z
101 - 110 = 1111 :  +5  -  +6  =  +15 [-1] C
101 - 111 = 1110 :  +5  -  +7  =  +14 [-2] C
110 - 000 = 0110 :  +6  -  +0  =  + 6 [-2] 
110 - 001 = 0101 :  +6  -  +1  =  + 5 [-3] 
110 - 010 = 0100 :  +6  -  +2  =  + 4 [-4] 
110 - 011 = 0011 :  +6  -  +3  =  + 3      
110 - 100 = 0010 :  +6  -  +4  =  + 2      
110 - 101 = 0001 :  +6  -  +5  =  + 1      
110 - 110 = 0000 :  +6  -  +6  =  + 0      Z
110 - 111 = 1111 :  +6  -  +7  =  +15 [-1] C
111 - 000 = 0111 :  +7  -  +0  =  + 7 [-1] 
111 - 001 = 0110 :  +7  -  +1  =  + 6 [-2] 
111 - 010 = 0101 :  +7  -  +2  =  + 5 [-3] 
111 - 011 = 0100 :  +7  -  +3  =  + 4 [-4] 
111 - 100 = 0011 :  +7  -  +4  =  + 3      
111 - 101 = 0010 :  +7  -  +5  =  + 2      
111 - 110 = 0001 :  +7  -  +6  =  + 1      
111 - 111 = 0000 :  +7  -  +7  =  + 0      Z
```

Where C is a carry out/borrow and Z is zero

Your rule is strictly an unsigned rule.  For signed I think it is something like if N != V then signed less than, if N == V then signed greater than.

so 0 - 0 is 0 Z flag they are equal
then 0 - 1 and 0 - 2 ,etc.  the second operand is greater Z not set and Carry set.

Until we get to 1 - 0 that is not zero and C is not set the left number is greater.

Then we hit the equal (1 - 1)

And some more Z not set C set so the right number is greater.

Then 2 - 0, 2 - 1 left is greater (Z not set C not set) and then 2 - 2 Z is set, then 2 - 3 to 2 - 7 Z not set C set so right is greater.

And this pattern repeats.

The trick of course is what is the definition of source and destination, that is often not documented in the instruction set, you have to experimentally determine that and for some reason at least for me I always guess wrong.

Your specific example

1 compared to 4   1 - 4  = 1 + (-4), 4 = 0b100, so -4 = 011 + 1

feed the adder, subtract means invert the carry in and invert the second operand:

```
     1
   001
+  011
=======
```

fill it in

```
  0111
   001
+  011
=======
   101
```

1 - 4 = -3.  Z is 0 C is 0 so 1 < 4

Note to get a borrow bit out of a carry bit you invert the carry (borrow = ~carry).  Carry out is 0 means a borrow happened which is obvious if you tried to subtract 4 from 1 using pencil and paper in decimal.

If there was no borrow then the carry out is set, for example take 4 - 1:

```
  1001
   100
+  110
========
   011
```

4 - 1 = 3 with no borrow.   Z is not set C is set so 4 > 1

I think the bottom line here is which operand is source and which is destination, and why do they rarely document it properly?  ANY time you use a compare in an instruction set you have to do a few experiments with fixed numbers to see which operand is which.  You also have to be very careful to use signed or unsigned greater than or less than it makes a difference.  Some instruction sets dont offer one flavor or the other but that is okay you really do not need a long list of signed and unsigned this and that switching the operands left and right and understanding the flags you can find a simple if carry or not carry or if whatever gives you almost everything, and sometimes you get the added bonus of when Z is set then Carry is a zero right so that means the carry not set is a "or equal".

Comment: Hey, I finally started to understand the conecpt. When computing 1 - 4 the carry is 0, but it's being inverted so it's 1. That's the piece of the puzzle that was missing so I couldn't understand why the carry flag was set. One last question, how does the hardware know when to invert the carry bit, and when to leave it as-is? Thank you so much!

Comment: Each instruction set or processor design arm vs x86 vs powerpc, etc has different designers that do different things.  Twos complement allows us to not need to make subtract logic as that doesnt make any sense, instead you use add logic and invert the second operand and invert the carry in, normally the carry in for an add is 0 on the first bit cell, but for a subtract making that a 1 means +1 so you get your invert and add 1 (twos complement negate  a - b = a + (-b)).

Comment: now some architectures do and some architectures do not invert the carry out on a subtract, the going into the adder stuff you have to do the going out you dont.  the best way to find out is to just do an experiment on that processor.  and/or examine the carry and other flag definitions for greater than less than and such that will also tell you.  It matters in the output flags and how you use them it also matters if the processor has a subtract with borrow as to whether that subtract inverts the carry in or not.

Comment: there is not one rule, there is no god of computer architecture that dictates, in fact if you copy someone elses design too closely there are gods (lawyers and judges) that will make you suffer.  So some processor families have a carry out on a subtract which is not inverted and others a borrow that is inverted.  And it would make sense that once you choose that path you stick with it, I would not expect x86 compatibles for example to flip flop and change the definition every now and again, but there is no reason for arm to do it the same way as x86...

Comment: No lawyers dont care if everyone uses a borrow, wont get sued for that but there are architecture things in processor design that are patented and you have to stay away from them...i wonder how hard it is to come up with a new architecture without someone claiming you violated their patent in some country.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the carry bit just the next most significant bit of the result.

Consider subtract a "complement, add 1, add" all in one step. In hardware, this is implemented with a carry-in to the LSB: 0 for add, 1 for sub, C for addc.

Examples:

1 - 4

```
  0.001       // 1
  1.011 + 1   // 4 complemented, carry in
+ -----
  1.101       // -3, carry out
```

-1 - -2

```
  1.111     // -1
  0.001 + 1 // -2 complemented, carry in
+ -----
  0.001     // 1, no carry out
```

The CMP condition codes you show are for unsigned arithmetic. For signed arithmetic, you have to exclusive-or the carry and sign bits. There is usually a test for this as well.

E.g., JG (Jump Greater) is ZF = 0 and SF = OF

EDIT, thanks to prodding from @Blechdose, here is an example of what happens when the sign of the complemented subtrahend is not propagated into the CF (causing x86 to invert the CF for subtract):

1 - 4

```
   .001       //  1
   .011 + 1   //  4 complemented, carry in
+ -----
  0.101       // -3, no carry out
```

4 - 1

```
   .100       //  4
   .110 + 1   //  1 complemented, carry in
+ -----
  1.011       //  3, carry out
```

Comment: I see your point, yet let's assume that the processor we're messing with is a 3-bit processor. How the carry takes place, when there's no room for the extra column you've just showed me?

Comment: The extra column is just a repetition of the sign bit in the number. It doesn't take any extra room. The result of the sum of that "extra" column, along with the carry in from bit 3, is the carry out.

Comment: You also happened to use a really bad twos complement value: note that the bit representation of 4 and -4 is really the same. This is a known "gotcha" in twos complement. There is no 3-bit representation of 4 in 3-bit twos complement. Try your example with smaller values, say 1 and 3.

Comment: Actually, that is a part I have problems with as well. When I do the 1-4 thing with 2's complement, Example with imaginary 4 bit register: I do not get a carry bit: 0001 (1) - 0100 (4) = 0001 (1) + 1100 (-4) = 1101 (-3). At least the carry is not generated from a carry from the highest bit. I would get a BORROW when I do a dual substraction 0001 (1) - 0100 (4), but that is not how the CPU is calculating it, right? It will use 2 complement.

Comment: The CMP condition codes you show are for unsigned arithmetic. For signed arithmetic, you have to exclusive-or the carry and sign bits. There is usually a test for this as well. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I know the CMP condition codes I showed are for unsigned arithmetic, but I comapred two positive, unsigned numbers - (+1) and (+4), shouldn't it work?

Comment: @Blechdose I checked what you said on MASM using AL register. the carry bit *is* being set when subtracting 4 (100b) from 1 (1b)

Comment: Yes, think of the negate and add happening in one step. The sign extends to the left.

Comment: @Doug currie If the carry flag is being set because the sign extends to the left, what's the difference between carry flag and sign flag?

Comment: @NoamSolovechick I know, that it is set. My question was more about, why is it set. Are there different rules of setting the carry flag, when you do a substraction? Why should the carry flag be set by sign extend to the left? Then it should be set for 6-4, as well, when the 2's complement of 4 is made.

Comment: The carry flag wouldn't be set if the add canceled out the propagation of the carry from the sign bit (i.e., if the carry out of the MSB was a one, it would wipe out the ones from the extending sign in this case). As far as add, or subtract is concerned, the carry flag is just the next more significant bit of the result.

Comment: @NoamSolovechick: if you are trying to compare to 4, use at least 4 bits, as 4 is larger than the maximum positive integer you can represent as a 3 bit signed integer.

Comment: @NoamSolovechick: Just in case your misunderstanding is about carry flag and signed flag. CF is set, when you add 2 numbers and the result is too big for the register to save it. Example: Lets say your register can only contain 4 bit. The biggest number, you can save in a 4 bit register is 1111 (15). When you now calculate 12+4=16, your result is too big for the 4 bit register. You would need 5 bit to represent 16: 1100 (12) + 0100 (4) =1 1000 (16), This is the condition which sets the CF = 1.

Comment: @DougCurrie Is your example for a 3 bit register and the number infront of the "." is the "carry" bit in 1.101?

Comment: @Blechdose: yes, that was the idea.

Comment: Okay, nevermind. I finally found the answer after reading questions here for 1 hour....  The CF is inverted when doing subtraction, at least for x86. Thus, when there is no carry out of the MSB, when doing a subtraction, then there must be a borrow instead. Because of that the CPU sets the CF=1.